# Getting "element not visible" using selenium python for SAP EPM browser application

Tags: python, selenium, sapui5

I am trying to automate an SAP EPM Application using Selenium Python. It's a browser based application. I am able to open the home page, after that I have to click on one tile. But I was unable to click it. It says "element not visible".

I tried using xpath, id but no luck.

[image: Tile "Change PM Order"]

Tile HTML:

```
<div class="tile tile-webdyn draggable tileBGColor ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle 
                 ui-droppable border-norm" id="PLANCHGWO" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="tileName">
    <center>Change PM Order</center>
  </div>
  <div class="tileImage">
    <center>
      <img width="50px" height="50px" src="EDWO.png">
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML relating to the title in question?

Comment: <center>Change PM Order</center>

Comment: From my experience SAP web apps uses dynamically generated elements so it would be much tougher to implement a solution without proper context.  At a glance I'd say first, check that you are referencing the correct element and that it's actually visible and available.

Comment: You need to include more relevant information. Please include a good chunk of the HTML around the element. As @Krrr also said, SAP web apps use dynamic generation (I'm not aware of how SAP apps work, so you'll have to ask Krrr for more info), so you may want to employ explicit waits such as WebDriverWait to aid you.

Comment: `<center>Change PM Order</center>` is a text of the element.  You won't be able to do much about it.  Try looking up the actual `button` or `div`.

Comment: will this work  -   <div class="tile tile-webdyn draggable tileBGColor ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-droppable border-norm" id="PLANCHGWO" style="position: relative;"><div class="tileName"><center>Change PM Order</center></div><div class="tileImage"><center><img width="50px" height="50px" src="EDWO.png"></center></div></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try invoking a `wait`, then click the desired WebElement with Javascript to work around the `not visible` error you are seeing.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



# wait for element to exist, then store it in tile variable
tile = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//center[text()='Change PM Order']")))

# click the element with Javascript
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", tile)
```

If this does not work, we will probably need to see the full page HTML to understand the element you are trying to click. It's possible it is hidden in an `iframe` or obscured by other elements on the page.

Comment: Thank you Christine, It worked, i am able to click. So do you suggest to use click with java script in SAP applications, I think normal click  using python might not work

Comment: It really depends on the scenario. If a python `click()` throws an error, then you can try Javascript. If Javascript does not work, there is usually another underlying error, meaning Python `click()` actually might work if used correctly. But in your case, WebElement looks very dynamic -- which usually requires Javascript click. It all depends on the site you are automating.